# Configure Command line is missing from phpinfo

Tags: apache, config, php-ini, php

In my php info Configure command line is missing as it should be present like below image.

[image]

How to achieve this in my php info. My server is plesk 12 server operating system cent OS 6.6

Comment: Seems that the attached image is not loaded. Can you tell more info regarding the version, system, build date and architecture?